# Org Chart in html breaking to next line

Tags: html, css

I made an Org chart structure in html/css I will render a binary tree in the org chart so all nodes will have maximum two childs. But there is some problem with the css which is breaking chart to next line if the chart gets big or the screen is small. I just want some help with the css so that it displays a scrollbar and the tree doesnot break.

```css
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tree.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tree">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Parent</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>Child 1</div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div>Child-1-1</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>Child-1</div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <div>Child-1-1</div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <div>Child-1-2</div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>Child 2</div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div>Child-2-1</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>Child-2-2</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `padding-left` in `.tree ul` and add min-width in first `ul`

```css
.tree {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.tree > ul {
   min-width: 500px;
}
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tree.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tree">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>Parent</div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>Child 1</div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div>Child-1-1</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>Child-1</div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <div>Child-1-1</div>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <div>Child-1-2</div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>Child 2</div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div>Child-2-1</div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>Child-2-2</div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is still breaking when I reduce screen size

Comment: I have update my code. please check it small screen